# Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'file' to 'folder'

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

I try to upload an image to a directory on localhost.

Here is the part in my php file, which causes the error:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/uploads")) {
    echo "The file " . basename($filename) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

If I load the page, I get the following:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/folders/np/sln14hvn3tsbzc4kpjjtp17c0000gn/T/phppJbFJK' to '/Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/uploads' in /Users/sandro/Documents/bildgalerie/control/upload.php on line 31
```

Comment: a) does the target directory _exist_? b) does your webserver have _write access_ to the target directory? c) [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) needs a filename as target, not a directory.

Comment: Check directory permission, it should be 755

Comment: give permission to your destination directory

Comment: I forgot that move_uploaded_file needs a filename instead of a path.. thank you!